# How to build a map without controlling it "SLAM"

Tags: ros, slam, localization, navigation, 2d-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ROS comunity.

I'm trying to make a 2D map using navigation stack, gmapping, teleop_twist_keyboard, dephtimage_to_laserscan and freenect_launch. I'm having some troubles by the moment with that, but I'm close to generate the map.

The thing is, I'd like afterwards make my robot drive itself through an unknown, indoors planar environment in order to building a map. What other packages should I use? or should I keep using the ones I'm currently using for that? Is it necessary use more sensors like ultrasonic sonars?

I hope you can guide me in that part.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269765/how-to-build-a-map-without-controlling-it-%22slam%22/) by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-08-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-28**:
You should read this setup guide: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup

**Comment by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on 2017-08-28**:
Thanks, so I should try another method to make autonomous mapping? which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you're looking for something like [frontier_exploration](http://wiki.ros.org/frontier_exploration).

Other packages that implement similar things exist, such as [turtlebot_exploration_3d](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_exploration_3d).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on 2017-09-05**:
Thanks a lot gvdhoon for your reply. Once everything is working, I'll try to implement frontier_exploration. But, for SLAM itselft which other programs could be useful for reaching that?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-05**:\

> But, for SLAM itselft which other programs could be useful for reach that?

that is a different question, so I'd advise you to open a new one.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-05**:
If #q270227 was really about: "which SLAM component should I use?", then go ahead and undelete & re-open it. But do please update the question then as it was not clear to me what it was about.

**Comment by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on 2017-09-05**:
Yes, I've uploaded the other question and marked this one as answered. But I haven't enough points to reopen that question, only for undelete.